# Excel: Auto Indexing multiple tables

Tags: excel

I am making an excel sheet where I have multiple tables with different values, and each table has a list of items, differing each one from another. The problem is that I use multiple tables, therefore I cant use the method `=ROWS($A$1:A1)`, because sometimes the starting index will be in another cell, get me?

If someone can help me it would be really nice!

Thanks!

[Example of what I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KobJR.png)

Comment: I don't I'm afraid. Can you show some sample data and expected outcome? Talk through how  =ROWS($A$1:A1) applies to these tables.

Comment: Its just a number to index the products, like a list. But each table has its own list, get it? Btw, I want to make it all automatically, therefore I can't copy and paste stuff, not by myself.

Comment: Are you just wanting to add a index to each tables of 1,2,3 etc?

Comment: "multiple tables with different values" <--- may I know.. is the data on the same sheet? When you say different, are these tables have different number (and type) of columns?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to add row numbering which you can do using structured referencing.

You can use formula

```
=ROW(Table1[@]) -ROW(Table1[[#Headers],[columnName]])
```

Adjust Table name and columnName for where inserting.

[image: 2 tables]

Comment: That's kinda what I was looking for but I forgot to clear out that I'm not using actual tables, just trying to make indexes in normal cells, and starting them again where I want

Comment: why not convert them to tables?

Comment: Its already done like that, Im just making something I've been asked for

Comment: You are likely going to need to write vba then to apply to each table. Loop using Range.Find to find each cell in first column with Item in and offset one as you start position. Use Range.Find on adjacent column to find Sub-Total or Total as you end point for each table and then fill down incrementally in between.